# Forbid "rename" to copy a file

Tags: c++

[rename](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/) actually copies file (at least on `Windows 10` platform) if the `newname` points to a different drive.

Is there a way to avoid this? I would like it to just fail in this case.

Let's suppose I want to move 100 GB file. I would like to just rename it, if possible. If not - I would like to use my own copy function and show the user progress of the operation.

Comment: Renaming is not possible when files reside in different volumes, because the file directory on each volume is different. It's like "renaming" a tomato from one fridge to another, somehow you must transfer it first. When it's one volume, renaming only changes an index.

Comment: I know it! I'm talking about c++ rename function implementation! Read question please.

Comment: `Is there a way to avoid this?` - determine if the paths belong to different drives before calling rename, and if they do, do not call rename?

Comment: Is there a crossplatform way to determine this? I don't think it's a simple task.

Comment: Just check if the paths have the same volume before calling the fucntion

Comment: "drives" are a concept peculiar to windows. This won't happen on *nix OSs (like Linux, osx, Android), so just check it when you determine you're on windows.

Comment: It's volumes, not letter drives. Even if linux, a "rename" will still copy+delete if the file is to be placed on a different volume, no matter the mount point.

Comment: In order to call `rename`, you must first compose the paths according to the rules of the OS, as it is stated in the documentation. Hence, you must be aware prior to calling `rename` which OS you are on, so that you can follow the path composition rules. Hence, you should be able to tell from the paths whether they belong to the same volume, by picking the way of telling that corresponds to the OS.

Comment: @GSerg this is generally not easy on cases when mount points are, in linux how do you know if /etc and /dev are belonging to the same volume? You *cannot* deduce volume information from just a path.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I understand you cannot deduce from paths alone, but there must be a platform-specific way to ask the OS, and you should be able to pick the correct platform-specific way because you have to be aware of your OS before calling `rename`. E.g. for Windows it would be https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170707-00/?p=96555.

Comment: @GSerg yes, in Windows there is [GetVolumePathNameW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumepathnamew)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to create a hard link to the new destination. If it fails, it fails. If it succeeds, you remove the original file. I verified that this works for files (not directories) on Linux (g++ 8.3.1 and clang++ 7.0.1) and Windows (VS2019) and expect it to work on most of the other modern OS:es too. C++17 (or `boost` for older compilers) is required.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

bool my_rename(const std::string_view from, const std::string_view to,
               std::error_code& ec)
{
    // create hard link
    std::filesystem::create_hard_link(from, to, ec);

    if(ec) return false; // it failed

    // remove the original
    return std::filesystem::remove(from, ec);
}

int cppmain(const std::string_view program, std::vector<std::string_view> args) {
    if(args.size() != 2) {
        std::cerr << "USAGE: " << program << " <source> <target>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::error_code ec;

    if(my_rename(args[0], args[1], ec) == false) {
        std::cerr << program << ": " << ec << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return cppmain(argv[0], {argv + 1, argv + argc});
}
```

Comment: I like this! That `cppmain` is nice too (if a little copy/allocate-happy - do a `string_view` version!)

Comment: :-) Thank's! Yes, not the most effective program startup, but nice to deal with afterwards. Will look into a `string_view` version.

Comment: [Boom!](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43a1a34c2bd9fb6e) Drop-in. :) Sadly the vector still allocates but only once and only cheaply so yay

Comment: :-D Nice, but I'd rather have `std::string&` or `filesystem::path&` as arguments to `my_rename`. Perhaps solvable without too much fuzz.

Comment: Why do you want to create a `std::string` when you don't need to? A `std::string_view` can be created from a literal or from an existing `std::string`, so you don't lose any functionality but potentially lose a completely unnecessary and very temporary dynamic allocation and string copy! That's why they added it :) IMO a `const std::string&` function arg should pretty much always be a `const std::string_view` now. Exceptions include reeeeeally tight loops on platforms where adding a "length" argument (i.e. one pointer+size, versus just a reference i.e. pointer) is prohibitive.. but that's rare

Comment: Oh, ok, makes sense! Updated! Excellent, I'll use this pattern in the future.

Comment: Note that there are file systems which don't support hard links where this approach will fail, e.g. FAT or BFS (the Be File System, used by BeOS and Haiku).

Comment: @JoachimMairböck OP wants to implement a `rename` that fails rather than copy/remove so I think the approach in the answer does what OP wants on those filesystems.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, because a legitimate rename on the same volume would also fail in this case.

Comment: @JoachimMairböck Aha, I see what you mean. Well, in that case one will probably have to resort to platform specific calls to check if a rename is possible without copy if the above function fails

Answer (score 2):

If in Windows, you can use [MoveFileEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexa) without MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED.
You can also use [GetVolumePathNameW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumepathnamew) to determine whether source and destination belong to the same volume and, therefore, if a copy would be (probably) needed or not.

Comment: What about macOS, Linux, Android?

Comment: Someone that knows these OSes might post an answer, if it exists.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev I don't think you'll have that problem there. This 'feature' of `rename` is specific to Windows.

Comment: @PaulSanders it's the same "feature" no matter the OS. It's physical limitation.